# Book about three asteroids hitting Earth, underground bunkers, tunnels, portals and ancient giant civilization, portals work by placing hand

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi, underground-civilization

This book was a trilogy, I believe.

There were three asteroids heading for the Earth. All powerful people are in underground bunkers awaiting the destruction of parts of the planet. A team of people find a way in and discover underground tunnels and cities, once inhabited by giants. There are portals that can be used with a medallion and placing hand on the monolith. Also there are some white creatures that have the shape of a bat but are large and alien.

Comment: "A team of people find a way" inside asteroid or our planet? When did you read this book?

Answer (score 3):

The [Ancient Origins Series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/173766-ancient-origins) by Robert Storey.

The description of the first book (from Goodreads) is:

> In the near future Sarah Morgan, an English archaeologist, is in a race against time to prove the impossible: that an advanced human ancestor once populated the Earth.
>
> [...]
>
> Simultaneously the world prepares for the arrival of 2011 AG5, an asteroid that will impact off the South African coastline with the force akin to the strike that wiped out the dinosaurs 65 million years previous. Humanity has long been planning for this colossal event and many preparations have been made to counteract its after effects in order to preserve the ever fragile global economy and civilisation itself. As the world holds its collective breath, below the surface government-run clandestine subterranean facilities are gearing up for the challenges ahead.

Comment: Please provide information indicating why you think is the answer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you identify which book in particular, and describe the story so it's apparent how it matches the question?